# Como iniciar variables static de una clase usando un metodo asincrono en javascript

Tags: variables, static

Tengo la siguiente clase con variables static

```
class CryptoInfo {
static pairs = []
static quotes = []
static assets = {}
static async load() {
    await Promise.all([
        allPairs(),
        allAssets()
    ])
    .then(async ([allpairs, allassets]) => {
        return await Promise.all([
            new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve(allpairs.reduce((a, b) => {
                    if(this.quotes.findIndex(q => q === b.quote) < 0)
                        this.quotes.push(b.quote)
    
                    a[b.symbol] = {}
    
                    for(const property in b)
                        if(property != 'symbol')
                            a[b.symbol][property] = b[property]
    
                    return a
                }, {}))
            }),
            new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve(allassets.map(({assetName}) => assetName === 'IOTA' ? 'MIOTA' : assetName).toString())
            })
        ])
    })
    .then(async ([pairs, assets]) => {
        this.pairs = pairs

        return await metadata(assets)
    })
    .then(({data}) => this.assets = data)
}
```

}

Pero para iniciar las variables Static tengo que llamar desde fuera el metodo load()

```
await CryptoInfo.load()
```

Habra alguna forma de inicializar las variables sin tener que llamar al load desde fuera de la clase?